# SwiftUI Charts – X axis data points are not spaced equally by default

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

Trying to implement a chart into my app where it tracks your profit of a game over time. The idea is very simple, a line chart that shows your progress over the course of a year. I'm using dummy data for now while I style the chart, with dates in Jan, Feb, March, May, and December but for some reason the chart is skewing oddly because the data points are not spaced evenly across the X axis.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Code with dummy data below, as well as the image:

```swift
let dummyData: [dummySession] = [
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 1, day: 1), profit: 0),
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 2, day: 12), profit: 55),
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 3, day: 20), profit: 376),
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 5, day: 2), profit: 120),
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 5, day: 18), profit: 500),
    .init(date: Date.from(year: 2023, month: 12, day: 11), profit: 222)
]

VStack {
    Chart {
        ForEach(dummyData) { session in
            LineMark(x: .value("Date", session.date, unit: .month),
                     y: .value("Profit", session.profit))
            .lineStyle(.init(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        }
        .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
    }
    .chartXAxis {
        AxisMarks(stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0))
    }
    .chartYAxis {
        AxisMarks(position: .trailing, values: .automatic) { value in
            AxisGridLine()
            AxisValueLabel() {
                if let intValue = value.as(Int.self) {
                    Text(intValue.asCurrency())
                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.frame(maxHeight: 300)
```

[image: chart result]

Comment: The graph looks correct to me. How do you want it to look? Do you just not like this interpolation method? Try another interpolation method?

Comment: And perhaps remove `unit: .month`, because otherwise you would have 2 y values for the same x value of 2023 May.

Comment: It should more resemble a stock chart, evenly spaced data points along the x axis regardless if the user *only* played and input profits for the month of May, for example. I want it to automatically scale to evenly fill out the entirety of the X Axis if that makes sense.

Comment: But your data points are not evenly spaced. How do you expect it to figure out the data in between? Can you show a picture of your desired result?

Comment: Do you mean you want to skew the X axis so that the x values that are in your data are spaced evenly? Kind of like plotting the dates as *categorical* data?

Comment: Sweeper thanks for taking the time to follow up. Correct, I'd like the data skewed such that the data are evenly spaced. Since I won't be displaying an X Axis label, this will be Ok. I will add a photo of an example of a chart I'd like it to resemble. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Date`, you should create your own `Plottable` type that acts like a `String` (i.e. `primitivePlottable` returns a `String`). SwiftData treats strings as categorical data, and plots them with equal spacing.

```
struct YearMonthDay: Plottable, Hashable {
    init(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
    }
    
    init?(primitivePlottable: String) {
        guard let date = try? Date.ISO8601FormatStyle.iso8601.parse(primitivePlottable) else {
            return nil
        }
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        guard let day = components.day, let month = components.month, let year = components.year else {
            return nil
        }
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }
    
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
    
    var primitivePlottable: String {
        date.formatted(.iso8601)
    }
    
    // this will be useful later
    var date: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day))!
    }
}
```

The `DummySession` struct would then be declared as:

```
struct Session: Identifiable {
    let date: YearMonthDay
    let profit: Int
    
    var id: YearMonthDay {
        date
    }
}
```

When creating the chart, you should format the X axis labels in your desired format:

```
Chart {
    ForEach(data) { session in
        LineMark(x: .value("Date", session.date),
                 y: .value("Profit", session.profit))
        .lineStyle(.init(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    }
    .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
}
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks { value in
        if let yearMonthDay = value.as(YearMonthDay.self) {
            AxisValueLabel {
                Text(yearMonthDay.date, format: .dateTime.month().day())
            }
        }
    }
}
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(position: .trailing, values: .automatic) { value in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisValueLabel {
            if let intValue = value.as(Int.self) {
                Text(intValue, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                    .padding(.leading, 25)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]