# Swift Chart remove empty data from Graph

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

I'm trying to display a graph like the one from the default Stock app.
I'd like to hide or remove the parts of the graph where there is no data.
For example, if I have a week where I have data on Monday, Tuesday and Friday, I don't want to show the range from Thursday to Wednesday.

I can achieve this behavior by using a `String` as my X axis, but I'm loosing the ability to format properly the labels.
If I use a `Date` as my x axis, I get a proper linear progression in my axis but then I get long ranges without data.

Is there anyway we can keep an x axis of type `Date` while still "compacting" or removing part where there is no data?

Comment: "but I'm loosing the ability to format properly the labels" Can you explain this? Does [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77642190/5133585) help?

Comment: Thx @Sweeper, it does help indeed! I'm gonna try to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transform the date value into string, then it will only show the single values, e.g. like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let chartData: [(date: Date, value: Double)] = [
        (date(5,2,2024), 112),
        (date(8,2,2024), 124),
        (date(9,2,2024), 116),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(chartData, id: \.date) { item in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", item.date.formatted()),
                    y: .value("Value", item.value)
                )
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```