Handling of dates with no value when creating a date bar chart in Charts
Some data have skipped dates, as in the following data.
TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-05-12 07:37:30 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 0.0),
TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-01 15:00:00 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.5, totalVolume: 105.0),
TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-03 15:00:00 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 100.0)

In this case, the graph shows nothing for the corresponding date. As shown in the image.

Is it possible to create a continuous graph by displaying only the data with values and not the dates with no values?
I want to create a bar chart with only dates with values.
The source code is as follows
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct TrainingSession {
    var date: Date
    var maxRM: Double
    var totalVolume: Double
}

struct GraphView: View {
    var sessions: [TrainingSession]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // 最大RMのグラフ
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("最大RM")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    Chart(sessions, id: \.date) { session in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Date", session.date),
                            y: .value("Max RM", session.maxRM)
                        )
                    }
                    .chartXAxis {
                        AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day, count:7)) // 日付の表示間隔を調整
                    }
                    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal) // 横スクロールを有効にする
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
                }

                // 総負荷量のグラフ
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("総負荷量")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    Chart(sessions, id: \.date) { session in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Date", session.date),
                            y: .value("Total Volume", session.totalVolume)
                        )
                    }
                    .chartXAxis {
                        AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day, count:7)) // 日付の表示間隔を調整
                    }
                    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal) // 横スクロールを有効にする
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GraphView(sessions: sampleData)
    }

    var sampleData: [TrainingSession] {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
        return [
            TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-05-12 07:37:30 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 0.0),
            TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-01 15:00:00 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.5, totalVolume: 105.0),
            TrainingSession(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-03 15:00:00 +0000")!, maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 100.0)
        ]
    }
}

struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}



What about filtering (with filter()) the TrainingSession and removing the elements you don't want to show?

@Larme I could be wrong but I believe OP want to have the date points with values equally spaced on the x axis no matter what the actual time is between them. OP, I successfully did this by using indices instead but I don't know how to get the correct date labels then. maybe someone else does. Chart(sessions.indices, id: \.self) { index in

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77642190/5133585

The following modifications were made and it works correctly.
import SwiftUI
import Charts
import Foundation

struct YearMonthDay: Plottable, Hashable {
    init?(primitivePlottable: String) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: primitivePlottable) else {
            return nil
        }
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        self.year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        self.month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        self.day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    }
    
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
    
    init(date: Date) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        self.year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        self.month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        self.day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    }
    
    var primitivePlottable: String {
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
}


struct TrainingSession {
    var date: YearMonthDay
    var maxRM: Double
    var totalVolume: Double
}

struct GraphView: View {
    var sessions: [TrainingSession]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // 最大RMのグラフ
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("最大RM")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    Chart(sessions, id: \.date) { session in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Date", session.date.primitivePlottable),
                            y: .value("Max RM", session.maxRM)
                        )
                    }
                    .chartXAxis {
                        AxisMarks(values: .automatic) { value in
                            AxisValueLabel {
                                Text(value.as(YearMonthDay.self)?.primitivePlottable ?? "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
                }
                
                // 総負荷量のグラフ
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("総負荷量")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    Chart(sessions, id: \.date) { session in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Date", session.date.primitivePlottable),
                            y: .value("Total Volume", session.totalVolume)
                        )
                    }
                    .chartXAxis {
                        AxisMarks(values: .automatic) { value in
                            AxisValueLabel {
                                Text(value.as(YearMonthDay.self)?.primitivePlottable ?? "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            GraphView(sessions: sampleData)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width) // 画面の幅に合わせる
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Training Data")
                }

    }
    
    var sampleData: [TrainingSession] {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
        return [
            TrainingSession(date: YearMonthDay(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-05-12 07:37:30 +0000")!), maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 0.0),
            TrainingSession(date: YearMonthDay(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-01 15:00:00 +0000")!), maxRM: 10.5, totalVolume: 105.0),
            TrainingSession(date: YearMonthDay(date: formatter.date(from: "2024-06-03 15:00:00 +0000")!), maxRM: 10.0, totalVolume: 100.0)
        ]
    }
    
}

struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}



Please add a better explanation of what you have changed.
